# Sum of 2 columns and subtract another table's column from the result

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a beginner question. 
I have 2 Oracle tables
Table 1 has the following columns:
C1   C2   C3

And Table 2 has the following columns:
D1   D2   D3

I need help in making a summation in PL/SQL like
Sum(C1 * C2) - D1

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data in both tables and what the desired output would be for that data. Also add the PL/SQL you have tried with and where you got stuck.

Comment: Thanks for the prompt, actually i've submitted this question from my mobile and it's hard to provide the details you ask, i'll provide details as soon as i get to my work. Thank you again.

Answer (score 0):

Below is complete simple script, basically you would need to know how to define variables and iterate through rows. Let me know if you further explanation required.

```
  set SERVEROUTPUT ON;

    create table tab1(
      c1 number,
      c2 number,
      c3 number);

    create table tab2(
      d1 number,
      d2 number,
      d3 number);


    insert into tab1 values(10, 20, 30);
    insert into tab2 values(10, 20, 30);

    declare 
      first_val number := 0;
      second_val number := 0;
    begin

      for rec in ( select sum(c1*c2) as sum_c1 from tab1)
      loop
        first_val := rec.sum_c1 + first_val;
      end loop;  

      for rec in (select d1 as d1_val from tab2)
      loop
         second_val := rec.d1_val + second_val;
      end loop;

      dbms_output.put_line(first_val - second_val);
    end;
```